# Evaluate a mathematical expression with variable number of arguments

Tags: python, function, arguments

I have a mathematical expression I try to evaluate.
I've created a function called "evaluate" :

```
def evaluate(expression, list_var) :
```

It takes in argument the mathematical expression itself and the list of variables which it contains. For example this expression can be :

```
expr = "x + 3 - y"
```

Here, list_var should simply be :

```
list_var = [x, y]
```

I transform this expression into a function this way :

```
f = lambdify(list_var, expression)
```

then I want f to be evaluated on all the values corresponding to all my variables. Suppose I have a list which contains all the values associated to each of the variables I want to evaluate :

```
list_values = [value1, value2]
```

with value1 associated to "x" and value2 associated to "y".
I just want to execute :

```
f(value1, value2)
```

But how can I pass the list of these values as arguments of the function "f" I've just created ?
Because the numbers of arguments in "f" is depending on the number of variables and the number of values in my list so I don't know in advance how to call "f" with the correct arity

It should be easy but I'm novice in this so..
Thank you for helping me guys

Answer (score 0):

The * operator should help you out:

```
list_values = [1, 2]
f(*list_values)
```

Specifically the * operator unpacks the sequence and collects them into positional arguments.

Comment: ah nice ! It looks exactly the stuff I wanted to